# How to link parent async with multiple children asyncs

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

The documentation of the [`async` package](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.0/async-2.1.1.1/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) describes the `withAsync` function as:

> Spawn an asynchronous action in a separate thread, and pass its Async
>   handle to the supplied function. When the function returns or throws
>   an exception, uninterruptibleCancel is called on the Async. This is a
>   useful variant of async that ensures an Async is never left running
>   unintentionally.

I've been staring at that for the past 2 hours and haven't been able to figure out how to start a monitor thread, that spawns multiple worker threads, such that:

- If the monitor thread dies, all worker threads should be killed,
- **But,** if any worker thread dies, **none of the other worker threads should be affected.** The monitor should be notified and it should be able to restart the worker thread.

Comment: Curious: what's your use case? It sounds like you're trying to build an Erlang-esque supervision model, for which you might be better served by an actor library like [`pipes-concurrency`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson the use-case is to spawn a job-queue when my webapp starts. The job-queue internally spawns a job-polling thread and a job-listen/notify thread. If either of those threads die, they need to be re-spawned. If the app thread is killed, then the job-queue needs to be killed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we need two functions: one that starts all the async tasks and another that watches them and restarts them whenever they die.

The first one could be written like this:

```
withAsyncMany :: [IO t] -> ([Async t] -> IO b) -> IO b
withAsyncMany []     f = f []
withAsyncMany (t:ts) f = withAsync t $ \a -> withAsyncMany ts (f . (a:))
```

If we were using the [managed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/managed-1.0.5/docs/Control-Monad-Managed.html) package, we could also write it like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Managed (with,managed)

withAsyncMany' :: [IO t] -> ([Async t] -> IO b) -> IO b
withAsyncMany' = with . traverse (\t -> managed (withAsync t))
```

The restart function would loop the list of asyncs, polling for their status and renewing them when they fail:

```
{-# language NumDecimals #-}
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

resurrect :: IO t -> [Async t] -> IO ()
resurrect restartAction = go []
    where
    go ts [] = do
        threadDelay 1e6    -- wait a little before the next round of polling
        go [] (reverse ts)
    go past (a:pending) = do
        status <- poll a   -- has the task died, or finished?
        case status of
            Nothing -> go (a:past) pending
            Just _  -> withAsync restartAction $ \a' -> go (a':past) pending
```

I'm worried however about the possibility of many nested `withAsyncs` causing some type of resource leak (because some kind of exception handler must be installed with each `withAsync` to notify the child in case the parent thread dies).

So perhaps in this case it would be better to spawn workers with plain `async`s, store the collection of `Async`s into some kind of mutable reference and install a single exception handler in the monitor thread, which would traverse the container terminating each task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer, that uses `async` instead of `withAsync`. The main function is

```
monitor :: Int -> IO () -> IO ()
monitor count task =
    bracket (do asyncs <- replicateM count (async task)
                newIORef asyncs)
            (\ref -> forever (do
                threadDelay 1e6
                asyncs <- readIORef ref
                vivify task (writeIORef ref) asyncs))
            (\ref -> do
                asyncs <- readIORef ref
                mapM_ uninterruptibleCancel asyncs)
```

it uses an auxiliary `vivify` function that traverses a list of `Async`s, reviving dead ones and writing back the updated list to an `IORef`:

```
vivify :: IO () -> ([Async ()] -> IO ()) -> [Async ()] -> IO ()
vivify task write asyncs = go [] asyncs
    where
    go _    [] = do
        return ()
    go past (a:pending) = do
        status <- poll a
        case status of
            Nothing -> do
                go (a:past) pending
            Just _  -> do
                past' <- mask_ $ do
                    a' <- async task
                    write (reverse (a':past) ++ pending)
                    return (a':past)
                go past' pending
```

We mask asynchronous exceptions in the interval between creating a new `Async` and "persisting" it in the `IOref`, because otherwise if an asynchronous exception arrived inbetween and killed the monitor thread, that `Async` would remain dangling.